# How do I convert characters to a time that has fractional seconds without adding a date?

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert a string of characters to a time that retains the fractional seconds, but does not add a date to the data?

Background: Data that I saved overnight (starting at 22:00 and ending at 06:00) is recorded with a time, but not a date.
I would like to be able to perform something like an "if" statement on the times (i.e. if (time < midnight) date = yesterday.... else date = today)

I don't want to use something like strptime, because strptime adds today's date to the data:

```
> options(digits.secs=3)
> strptime("22:59:54.807", format="%H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2019-01-20 22:59:54.807 AEDT"
```

When I use times from the chron package, the fractional seconds are dropped:

```
> options(digits.secs=3)
> times("22:59:54.807")
[1] 22:59:55
```

Comment: lubridate package in R is your best bet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **base::strftime()**, you can obtain a character of the desired time to any divide of seconds you want. Below I have saved the current time to unit 1/1000 of a second, using the number "4" after "OS":

Using current system time:

`time = Sys.time()
str(time)`

> POSIXct[1:1], format: "2019-01-19 15:41:28.185"

`newTime = strftime(Sys.time(), format="%H:%M:%OS4")
str(newTime)`

> chr "15:41:28.1851"

`newTime`

> [1] "15:41:28.1851"

Comment: Thanks @JessicaBurnett, once I have the 'chr "15:41:28.1851"', how do you convert that back to a "time" that can be used in a conditional statement such as an "if" statement?